# authenticate Azure AD with Node.js via oauth2

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I want to authenticate users in Azure active directory with node js (I'm really new in azure and active directory), I read a lot of documentation, there exists two ways for doing it.
first: my web request authenticate through a form that Microsoft provides me, then user log-in and this redirect to a URL of mine <--- this way I don't need

second: (this is the way I need) I'm using Oauth2, with
`var BearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy` for authenticate, I have my client id, tenanId, client_Secret  etc.
As a first step I need get an Acces_token which I get send request to this URL via postman:

**https://login.microsoftonline.com/My_alias_tenan/oauth2/token**

I send these params on my body:
`{grant_type: client_credentials, client_id:  1f7bbc3e-19ed-4ae5-b16d..., client_secret: 98ijhi7tuf..., resource: https://management.azure.com/, .... }`

I just follow this blog: **https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/**

I received a token like this:

```
"token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1570045543",
    "not_before": "1570041643",
    "resource": "https://management.azure.com/",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV
```

which I enter in the header for my next request which is pointing to my localhost: because is here where I have my options to send the authenticate, and are this:

```
      identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/alias_tenan/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
      clientID: process.env.AD_CLIENT_ID,
      audience : 'https://management.azure.com/',
      validateIssuer: false,
      passReqToCallback: true,
      isB2C: false,  
      allowMultiAudiencesInToken: false, 
      issuer:null,
      loggingLevel: 'info',
      loggingNoPII: false,
      responseMode: query
```

I have my code like this:

```
    return passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', function(req, token, done) {
        console.log(token)    
        res.status(200).json({'name': 'name'});
    }
    )(req, res, next)
```

but always received this message:

```
    {"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"DESKTOP-U0R9GTV","pid":1168,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: error: invalid_token","time":"2019-10-02T22:54:04.782Z","v":0}
```

Has anyone done this successfully? thanks in advance
and I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of any npm packages, I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal for single signon. 
Another package that would be useful is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kdpw/msal-b2c-react

Any package relies on MSAL.